# Passing zip file in httpwebrequest body

Tags: c#, curl, httpwebrequest, zip

I am trying to implement the following cURL call with c# code:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/zip" -u admin:admin -X POST --data-binary @<path to .zip>  http://localhost:606060/content/test.json
```

I tried the following code, but the server is returning a 400 bad request code.

```
    ___________________________________________________
    MemoryStream postDataStream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter postDataWriter = new StreamWriter(postDataStream);

    postDataWriter.Write("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
    postDataWriter.Write("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}",
                            "myFileDescription",
                            "A sample file description");

    // Include the file in the post data
    postDataWriter.Write("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
    // Include the file in the post data
    postDataWriter.Write("Content-Disposition: form-data;"
                            + "name=\"{0}\";"
                            + "filename=\"{1}\""
                            + "\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n",
                            "myFile",
                            Path.GetFileName(filePath),
                            "application/zip");
    postDataWriter.Flush();

    // Read the file
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        postDataStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    fileStream.Close();
    postDataWriter.Write("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
    postDataWriter.Flush();

    // Set the http request body content length
    request.ContentLength = postDataStream.Length;

    // Dump the post data from the memory stream to the request stream
    using (Stream s = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        postDataStream.WriteTo(s);
    }
    postDataStream.Close();

    try
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        // I am getting exception on this line
        {
    .......................................................................
```

Actually the code I used here is for passing a file as a form parameter. In my case, there is no form and I am specifying the files path explicitly. I think the way I am  making the request is wrong. Is there any better way to make an httpwebrequest with C# corresponding to the cURL request I provided?

The documentation only says:

> The request body must contain the zip file .

Answer (score 1):

The curl command you use send the entire zip file contents in the body, plain and simple.

The source code you provide is a completely different beast as it implements multipart formpost content with headers and boundaries and all. It looks like you're overdoing it.

Use curl's --trace-ascii option and you can see exactly what it sends and you may realize the differences better.

Comment: My question is just how to do what you suggested. I mean, how should I modify the code, so that the request body contains only the zip file and the request become as simple as the cURL request.

Comment: I don't know C# and I'm not the person to ask. I simply spotted the differences based on the code you've written.